# open cv python cant open video

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
filename="C://Users//deniz//Desktop//cfg13131lol.avi"
codec= cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc("W", "M", "V", "2")
frameRate=30
resolution=(600,600)
videoFileOutput=cv2.VideoWriter(filename, codec, frameRate, resolution)
while True:
    red,frame=cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("webcam.",frame)
    frame = cv2.flip(frame,-1)
    if cv2.waitKey(1)& 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break
videoFileOutput.release
cap.release
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

path is correct but when I try to open it it says "0xc10100be".
I tried mp4 avi etc.

Comment: Have tried? You got outputs?

Answer (score 0):

Where you writing frame inside the loop.?, Looks like you missed that line.inside the loop.

```
videoFileOutput.write(frame)
```

Add this line to inside the loop.

```
import cv2
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
filename="C://Users//deniz//Desktop//cfg13131lol.avi"
codec= cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc("W", "M", "V", "2")
frameRate=30
resolution=(600,600)
videoFileOutput=cv2.VideoWriter(filename, codec, frameRate, resolution)
while True:
    red,frame=cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("webcam.",frame)
    frame = cv2.flip(frame,-1)
    videoFileOutput.write(frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1)& 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break
videoFileOutput.release
cap.release
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```